# Configure Vim to open in "easy mode" by default?

Tags: vim

I open Vim in "easy mode" with: `vim -y`

Is it possible to configure `.vimrc` to always open Vim in "easy mode" with just `vim` instead (without typing the `-y`)?

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22825/10604

Answer (score 0):

You can, since `vim -y` simply sets a number of options for that mode. It's possible to set those exact same options in the `vimrc` as well. They are shown in the `vim` [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#evim-keys) for `evim` (which is equivalent to `vim -y`), summarised below, see the link given for full detail:

```
These options are changed from their default value:
    :set nocompatible insertmode hidden backup backspace=2
    :set autoindent history=50 ruler incsearch mouse=a
    :set hlsearch whichwrap+=<,>,[,] guioptions-=a

Key mappings changed:
    <Down> <Up> Q <BS> CTRL-X <S-Del> CTRL-C <C-Insert> CTRL-V
    <S-Insert> CTRL-Q CTRL-Z CTRL-Y <M-Space> CTRL-A <C-Tab> <C-F4>

Additionally:
  - ":behave mswin" is used.
  - syntax highlighting is enabled.
  - filetype detection is enabled, filetype plugins and indenting is enabled.
  - in a text file 'textwidth' is set to 78.
```

You can also have a look into the actual source file used for this mode if you do the following within a `vim` session:

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim
```

This shows the actual code run when starting with `vim -y`.

---

But I suspect an easier way to do it, at least with a UNIX-style OS, would be to just set up an alias, something like the following in your start-up scripts:

```
alias vim='/usr/bin/vim -y`
```

This would allow command-line invocations to start with easy mode. It won't help non-command-line invocations but you could do that (in UNIXes *and* Windows) by providing a script earlier in the path to do so.

For example, you could create a `bash` script of the form:

```
/usr/bin/vim -y "$@"
```

and call it `vim`, ensuring that where you put it comes in the path *before* `/usr/bin`.

Comment: You can also just `:source` the evim script; see https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22825/10604